# SORBS blacklists IP over and over again

Tags: amazon-ses, spam, spam-prevention

I've got a problem with SORBS which still blacklists my IPs via which I send notifications to users (IPs are dedicated Amazon SES IPs). I report every ban in their support platform (support.sorbs.net), in first requests they suggested to implement `List-unsubscribe` header in emails - and I've done it.

Every de-list request seems similar - I'm writing which IP is banned, they require to explain why they should de-list this IP address, the answer is that I deliver notifications for users (which they've accepted during registration and they have opportunity to disable it). Still my IPS are blacklisted over and over again.

Have someone similar problem with SORBS spam trap? SORBS don't want to tell the exact reason for blacklisting my IPs.